# How to reinforce around large HVAC opening in subfloor

Tags: framing, ducts

The HVAC installer cut a large return grille for a pan return (I'm aware this is not ideal). I'm nervous about the floor/subfloor structure since it goes the long way (parallel to joists). How should I brace this? I was thinking of sistering a 2x4 along the length on the far side and putting flat sided 2x4s across the short way.

[image]

Comment: I rolled back your most recent edit. It removed some useful info, especially the picture. Without that, this would likely get closed as it needs more info.

Answer (score 2):

I would run upright 2x4 blocks crosswise as you suggest, but I'm not sure the point of the sistered 2x4. That doesn't do much for you unless you specifically need support on the edge of the hole.

I'd run blocks on 16" intervals<sup>*</sup>, along with one outside each end of the opening. I'd use 2x4 joist hangers on the far joist and face nail through the near joist. (If you were careful with your placement, toenails would be fine on the far joist.)

Use construction glue on everything to prevent noise and movement, and consider painting the blocks in flat black to reduce visibility.

---

<sup>*</sup> That's more frequent than is normally necessary for joists under 3/4" subfloor, but since we're dealing with an otherwise unsupported edge I think it's warranted.

Comment: The HVAC installer asked that I put the 2x4 blocking flat. I know that's not as strong as the long way but would that work?

Comment: Does it matter which way I toe screw ?

Comment: Well, sort of. I'd use two or three 3" screws at each junction. Get the angles right so you have good penetration.

Comment: I'm willing to bet the HVAC installer wants the blocks flat because that provides more support under the thin metal grate. My question, @Nate - why didn't _he_ put this blocking in to finish his job instead of getting you to do his job for him?

Comment: HVAC techs don't do framing. They're not qualified and it's outside scope. I'm not sure how flat blocks support the grate any more.

Answer (score 0):

Installing supports across the short direction will require a tighter spacing than 16" to get the same stiffness as the rest of the floor. Plywood is an "orthotropic" material, where its stiffness between your short supports is much lower than the joist-to-joist stiffness. My instinct is that the equivalent span under the lower stiffness is (16")0.25^(1/3) = 10", where I've assumed that your joists are spaced on 16" centers.

Use 2x2s instead of the 2x4s. Given the short span, they have effectively infinite stiffness. Just nail a 2x4 ledger to the inside of the joists on both sides, but spaced 1-1/2" down from the bottom of the floor sheathing. Install your support blocks between these ledgers and the bottom of the floor sheathing. Space them every 10". Screwing from above should be sufficient for fastening, with 3-1/2" screws reaching well into the support ledgers.

**Plywood Deflection**

For that 10" number, I used the max deflection spec of L/360 from the IRC and the shape of distributed load deflection expressions of CL^4/EI, where C is a constant that varies with support condition and load distribution. For joist-to-joist deflection, I have L/360 = CL^4/EI and I can solve for C as

C = (1/360)EI/L^3.

My recollection is that the weak direction stiffness of plywood is about 25% of the strong direction's stiffness. I want an L', then, that satisfies L'/360 = CL'^4/(0.25EI). This expression contains the same C as the earlier expression because it has the same load distribution and support conditions (running across your short, joist-like support blocks). Solving for L', I get

L' = [(1/360)(1/C)(0.25EI)]^(1/3),

and substituting the expression for C from earlier I get

L' = [(1/360)(360L^3/EI)(0.25EI)]^(1/3) = (0.25L^3)^(1/3) = L[0.25^(1/3)].

This expression provides the 10" spacing from earlier after substituting in the assumed 16" joist spacing for L.

**2x2 Strength**

For the adequacy of the 2x2s on 10" centers, I'll start with strength. #2 Southern Pine (you'll have to throw away chunks with substantial knots to achieve the #2 grade) has the worst case bending design stress of the softwoods, so I use its 1265 psi (1100 psi times the repetitive use factor of 1.15). Given effectively zero dead load and a 40 psf live load, the maximum span of a 2x2 is

[(1265psi)(1/6)(1.5in)^3(8/[(40psf)(10in)(1ft/12in)(1ft/12in)])]^0.5 = 45.3".

The 13" span lengths are well within bounds.

**2x2 Deflection**

For the 2x2's deflection, the worst case elastic modulus among the #2 softwoods is 1,300,000 psi. Sitting on top of the ledgers, I use a span length of 13" to find the deflection as

(5/384)(40psf)(10in)(1ft/12in)(1ft/12in)(13in)^4/[(1300000psi)(1/12)(1.5in)^4] = 0.0019".

L/360, the max deflection for a floor, is 13"/360 = 0.036". That's a deflection/max-deflection ratio of 5.3%, confirming the "effectively infinite stiffness" from earlier.

Comment: The joist bay is essentially 13" x 9" or so and the grate is 30" x 6". If I put the 2x4 in the traditional way (long way) it chokes off more of the bay than the short way, right?

Comment: @Nate, good call. Use 2x2s, then, spaced on 10" centers. I checked it really quick under the NDS for 2x4 material properties because 2x2s are technically outside the scope of the NDS. On 10" spacing they pass up to 45" length based on strength. Their deflection is equivalent to L/6900, where L/360 is the typical spec.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I have to finish this tonight so my only options are 2x4 on their side. I assume that is as good as 2x2 maybe a bit better. I'm going to put them on the sides of the grate. I'm also going to make a ledger/sister a 2x4 across the far joist because that subfloor doesn't continue. It's a staircase on the other side. That sound good?

Comment: @Nate, edge nailing is a trash connection. I assume that's your intention on the accessible side. I'd use ledgers on both sides. It's a bit more material, but I think it's probably easier too. Definitely worth it in my opinion, but maybe my mind is still stuck on the 2x2s. For 2x4s, edge nailing at one end probably isn't that big of a deal as long as you get tight joints.

Comment: @Nate, those aren't my details. My details are 10" block spacing and 2x2s supported on ledgers (face nailed under each block). Your details sound _okay_. I dislike the 3.5" obstructions with 10" spacing. I would use a table saw to divide the 2x4s, but then your edge nailing offends me.